# Application not exiting after terminating Actor and ActorSystem

Tags: scala, akka

I have a main program that creates an ActorSystem, an Actor and sends some messages to the actor. When the messages are processed I sent PoisonPill to kill the Actor. Then i shutdown the actor system.

Within the Actor I am calling Await to await for a future to complete. The problem I am facing is that the application is not exiting even though the actor is terminated by PoisonPill and ActorSystem is shutdown.

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val actorSystem = ActorSystem("sytem")
    val creationActor = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[MyActor], "MyActor")
    ...
    creationActor ! Message    //may be called multiple times
    creationActor ! PoisonPill
    ...
}
```

And the Actor code is

```
class MyActor extends Actor {

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case Message => {
       ...
      Await.result(Dataset.create(datasetId), 30 seconds) 
      //Dataset.create returns a Future. Also this method uses an
      //ExecutionContext of its own.
      ...
    }
  }

  override def postStop() = {
    context.system.shutdown()
  }
}
```

If I comment out the Await.result part, the program exits.

**EDIT:**
Looks like I have found the root cause.

The ExecutionContext that is used in Dataset.create(…) is the culprit. When i use a synchronous version of Dataset.create(…) which doesn't use Futures, my application exits.

The ec which Dataset.create() uses is defined like this 
`implicit val defaultContext = 
    ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100))`

Still curious to know why the asynchronous version doesn't exit the application.

**EDIT 2:**
If I change the Await part to

```
val future = BQDataset.create(datasetId)
future onComplete {
  case Success(d) => ...
  case Failure(e) => ...
}
```

still I face the same problem. 
As @cem-catikkas mentioned, the ExecutionContext which gets created when I call `BQDataset.create` is hanging around. I verified this by using jstack and could see `"pool-1-thread-1" prio=5 tid=0x00007ff49aa1e800 nid=0x4e03 waiting`

Comment: You should check the threads in the ExecutorService pool. Try shutting down the ExecutorService as well.

Comment: If you want to yield the true benefits of Actors you should "never" *block* inside an Actor's `receive` method. `Await` effectively does that. You should wrap your expensive operations in a Future and if required schedule that Future on a different thread pool (dispatcher).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I call `Dataset.create(…)`, the method creates an `ExecutionContext` and uses it to execute a third party library. This third party library opens a network connection and it doesn't have proper `shutdown()` or `close()` method  to cleanup the underlying connection.

Because of this, even if I call `ExecutionContext.shutdown()`, it wasn't able to shutdown the thread pool. That's why the application was not exiting.

Answer (score 2):

The actor is single threaded and handles messages one at a time.  Await is a blocking operation.  It sounds like the actor is busy doing `CostlyOp`.  The poison pill won't interrupt that, so the actor doesn't shut down until it processes all the costly ops in front of the poison pill.

Comment: Correct, the blocking Await call inside of the actor effectively makes it unable to process the PoisonPill right away. The motto is: Avoid Awaiting in actors at all costs.